# Spring Security OAuth2: Client as javascript application

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am using `client_credentials` grant type in my spring boot application. In client_credentials grant_type the client makes a request to the token endpoint. If the `access token request` is valid and authorized, the `authorization server` issues an access token.

```
localhost:8181/OUTPOST/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myClientId&client_secret=secret
```

The problem is my client is a javascript application. Client application wont be able to securely store the client credentials, so there is no point is having `client_secret`.

`Implicit`, `password` and `Authorization code` needs `user details` for generating token. But i dont have any user, i just need to validate my client application.

Which grant_type should i use to support my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The implicit OAuth2 flow is wat you are looking for. Details from the OAuth2 spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2

Comment: But as per my understanding implicit Oauth2 flow is used to validate user credentials. The implicit grant type does not include client authentication, and  relies on the presence of the resource owner.

Comment: If your client is a javascript app, you should use implicit OAuth2 (read the spec: "The implicit grant is a simplified authorization code flow optimized  for clients implemented in a browser using a scripting language such as JavaScript."). A javascript application is client side, therefore you can only use user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is really valid. It is not possible to authenticate a JavaScript client securely via OAuth2 without user credentials. This would mean that everyone that can access the JavaScript app would be authenticated.

If you want to restrict access to this app without user credentials, it might be better to add network level policies instead, like IP range whitelisting.